# Mocking with addition assignment (Mocking bytes() module)

Tags: python, testing, mocking

I have a program which goes as follows

```
data = bytes()
 ...
 
new_data = bytes()
 ...

data += new_data
print(data)
```

and so I have mocked bytes accordingly along with the `__iadd__` call as follows:

```
@unittest.mock.patch('file_name.bytes')
def test(self, mock_bytes):
   mock_bytes.__iadd__.return_value = mock_bytes
   ...
```

From my understanding, a MagicMock of `bytes()` should be returned, but instead I get a MagicMock of `bytes().__iadd__()`.

I'd appreciate any help on the matter :)

P.S. have also tried variations like `mock_bytes()`, `mock_bytes().__iadd__()`, or any other variation.

Answer (score 0):

In short, the mock works as expected. To override `data += new_data` you should have this syntax: `mock_bytes.return_value.__iadd__.return_value = "the value which is printed"`.

A note about mock syntax: you can often replace `.return_value` with `()`, so `mock_bytes.return_value.__iadd__.return_value = "the value which is printed"` is equivalent to `mock_bytes().__iadd__.return_value = "the value which is printed"`

Now, as to why you need the `()` / `.return_value` in the first place:

- Mocks are tied to the implementation - they mimic the functions called. So if you want to change the value of `data` variable in this line: `data = bytes()` you are changing **the return value** of the function `bytes`. You were right to identify that **iadd is called**, and once more, you want to change the return value.
- Then you have concatenation/chaining of calls: you are calling bytes, then **apply iadd on the returned object**. So you have this syntax: `mock_bytes.return_value.__iadd__.return_value = "the value which is printed"`